# delete specific part of a string and add another at the end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this span on my website with these values.

```
<span>1,4,4,7,5,9,10</span>
```

I want to use jquery to delete the `"1,"` (or what ever the first number is) from the beginning of the string and add `",12"` at the end (or any other number instead of 12) so it would look like this:

```
<span>4,4,7,5,9,10,12</span>
```

How can I do this with jquery or java script ?

Comment: I tried split(','); but every time I tried it chose a random ",".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span id="myText">1,4,4,7,5,9,10</span>
```

JS:

```
var text = $('#myText').html().split(',').slice(1);
text.push('12');
$('#myText').html(text.join(','));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/RD6W8/7/

Answer (score 2):

You can use split or regular expressions with string.replace

Here's how to use split:

```
var arr = '1,4,4,7,5,9,10'.split(',');
arr.shift();
arr.push('12');
var result = arr.join(',');
```

Or with regular expressions (not a very readable one I concede):

```
'1,4,4,7,5,9,10'.replace(/^\d+,(.*)$/, '$1,12')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span').text(function(i, t) {
   return t.replace(/\d+,/, '') + ',12';
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dnkEV/

Comment: To do all of it in regexp: `'1,4,4,7,5,9,10'.replace(/^\d+,(.*)$/, '$1,12')`

Answer (score 1):

Using DOM API, you can do this:

```
var tn = span.firstChild;

tn.deleteData(0, tn.data.indexOf(",") + 1);
tn.data += ",12";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KMzau/

---

Or like this:

```
var tn = span.firstChild;

tn.data = tn.data.slice(tn.data.indexOf(",") + 1) + ",12";
```